# Optimize some for loops?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I'm trying to dive deeper into C#, and so I've been experimenting with some code. I'm creating a console application that shows the path of a projectile depending on the angle, and it works great! you can check it out [here](http://goo.gl/57Lkto) actually. It's not perfect, but I like it.

My question is, is there a better way to use my for loops? I'm using 3 inside eachother, and I'm not sure if that should be an issue. If you could take a look at the code in the link, it'd be great. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I realized my code might not have shown up.

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Threading;
class Program
{    
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Clear();         
        DoArc();
    }

    static void DoArc() 
    {        
        int tempVal = 0;
        string displayLine = "";        
        for(int a = 0; a < 90; a+= 2) 
        {
            Console.Clear();
            for(int y = 0; y < 16; y++) 
            {                
                for(int x = 0; x < 40; x++) 
                {
                    tempVal = Mathf.RoundToInt(Physics.HeightAtPoint(x, a, 15f, 0));
                    tempVal = Mathf.Clamp(tempVal, 0, 16);                    
                    if (Mathf.CloseTo(16 - y, tempVal, 1)) 
                        displayLine += " X";
                    else
                        displayLine += " .";                    
                }
                Console.WriteLine(displayLine);
                displayLine = "";
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Angle: " + a);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: better to ask it on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, this could be a valid codereview post, assuming that code works.

Comment: Is it possible to redirect or do I need to post it again there?

Comment: post it again. just a simple copy paste

Comment: if you need to perform an action `x*y*z` times, then 3 for loops is pretty much necessary

Comment: about the only obvious improvement I can see would be to use a `StringBuilder` instead of appending all your text into the string `displayLine `. This would reduce memory costs as strings are immutable. Also, doing `displayLine = "";` doesn't actually free up memory.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no problem to solve with the code in question.

Comment: 16-y could also be calculated out of the inner loop instead of calculating it 40 times each time the inner loop runs.

Comment: @user2949024: People from different countries use different terminologies to describe the same things. Like I have seen distance represented with as both *s* and *x*. Please add comments in your code to specify what your important variables represent. Best would be to name the variables as to what they really are, i.e. use *distance* for representing distance instead of *x* or *s*.

Comment: I am voting to close because this is not an optimization but a code review question. To optimize remove the `Thread.Sleep()` calls, write to a string and in the end display the string. Separate calculation from visualization.

Comment: @user1666620, I am resetting the displayLine because I am displaying each line one after another.

Comment: @user2949024 if you don't use a `StringBuilder` (which I strongly recommend in this case for reasons I gave earlier), then declare the string at the start of the second for loop - that way you won't need to explicitly reset it every time.